# The validation loss can't improve at the beginning with MobileV2 in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I used two different models for my case.
The case is classification for different type of surface defect.
The input shape is (200, 200, 1), and there are 6 classes.
The numbers of training data is 1440(240 for 1 class), and the number of validation data is 360(60 for 1 class).

The training process is very well with first model. Both training loss and validation loss are dropping very quickly.
After that, I want to use MobileNetV2 from keras for comparing the training result. The training loss and accuracy in MobileV2 are improve, but the validation accuracy stuck in 0.1667(the loss is bumpy).

I wonder know what causes this result, Can I call this situation 'Over-fitting'? Or just this model is too deep to my case?

First model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
import parameter

input_shape = (parameter.IMAGE_SIZE_Y, parameter.IMAGE_SIZE_X, parameter.channel)

def MyModel():    

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape = input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())   

    model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))

    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'softmax'))

    model.summary()

    return model
```

Second model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
import parameter

def MyMobileNetV2():

    input_shape = (parameter.IMAGE_SIZE_X, parameter.IMAGE_SIZE_Y, parameter.channel)

    model = MobileNetV2(input_shape = input_shape,
                        include_top = False,
                        weights = 'imagenet')

    x = model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dense(1280, activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    predictions = Dense(6, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros')(x)

    model = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.01)

    loss = "categorical_crossentropy"

    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = True

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,    
                  loss=loss,
                  metrics=["accuracy"])

    model.summary()

    for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
        print(i, layer.name, layer.trainable)



    return model
```

Comment: I can suggest to use a smaller `lr` like `0.0001` since you are adopting imagenet weights and it is already trained. You may even learn from scratch since `imagenet` and your problem domain are completely different.

Comment: I would recommend freezing at least the first 40 layers or so in the imported network. This way, you can take advantage of some features the pretrained network has learned but also teach it features of your dataset. I also recommend lowering learning rate to .001 or lower.

Comment: thanks for your comment!

I tried all of your suggestion, and got better result.
But the MobileV3 model is still worse than simple CNN built by myself.
I think the reason is datasets is too easy, it doesn't need such a complicated model.
Anyway, thanks you for letting me know another way to tune my model.